# WooCommerce Bulk "Link All Variations"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a products page that will include all of my products. I have created 11 attributes with varying numbers of terms and I want to bulk create my products - but woo-commerce currently limits me to 50 products at a time.  So I spend a lot of time running down the list to see which products were created and which still need to be made.

Basic Example:

Clothing Category: Shirts, Shorts, Under Garments

Clothing Type: Long Sleeve, Short Sleeve, Tank top, Mesh, Khaki, Jean, socks, underwear, bra

Size: YS, YM, YL, AXS, AS, AM, AL, AXL, AXXL

Color: red, green, blue, yellow, orange, pink, purple, etc

Design: circles, boxes, triangles, etc

Say I want to mass create variations of the all of the above, but it exceeds the 50 "link all variations" limit.  How would I go about creating them all without creating each one individually/manually?

I read mention of someone using an XLS/CSV file for this but within the comments people stated that this didn't work well with variable products.  I have seen several mentions of additional plug-ins but I wanted to make sure there wasn't an easier way to do this before I went down that route.

Help??

Comment: Show us some detailed examples of what you've tried already.

Comment: Isn't it a limit of 50 variations at a time? So, in theory, couldn't you just repeat the creation of variations until they are all made? (Totally not sure but just wondering 'aloud')

Comment: I have tried manually entering them all but in reality, the number of varied parts I have to add are HUGE.  For one part - I have 187 variations.  Thats one part out of 19 for that series - so 187 x 19 = 3,553 individual parts.

Comment: So i've researched some more and I came across this convo http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53750/too-many-variations-in-woocommerce and I'm having the same issues as this person.  I have too many variations and I cannot load them at the same time.  I have thought of separating the parts, but even then I would have too many to upload at one time.
I'm confused as to where they are changing the upload qty.  On the server? or within WooCommerce??

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is looking to change the php to allow more than 50, just go to:
plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax.php     Line 593 for me

```
wc_maybe_define_constant( 'WC_MAX_LINKED_VARIATIONS', 100000 );
```

Note: I ended up using a single variation with every option set to "Any".  This was the easiest to manage in my case